# I would like to import a hosted .xml URL into google cloud storage formatted into .csv

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am using cloud functions to try to import an xml hosted URL like this:

```
from io import BytesIO
from google.cloud import storage
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import urllib.request
import datetime
import os
import wget
import logging

project_id = 'ID'

bucket_name = 'BUCKETNAME'
date_string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")
destination_blob_name = 'NAME'+date_string+'.csv'


source_file_name = 'NAMEexport.xml'

def upload_bloburl(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):   
    storage_client = storage.Client() 
    
    file = urllib.request.urlopen(source_file_name)

    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

blob.upload_from_string(ET.tostring(files, encoding='UTF-8',xml_declaration=True, method='xml').decode('UTF-8'),content_type='application/xml')
    
    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name))

    return f'Success!'
    
upload_bloburl(bucket_name, source_file_name,destination_blob_name)
```

My requirements.txt is the following:

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
requests==2.20.0
google-cloud-storage
urllib3
datetime
os
logging
wget
```

Unfortunately this doesn´t work. I am also not really familiar with Python, so probably there is an obvious mistake on my site. If anyone could help me, it would be amazing.

I wanted it to save a .csv file in the cloud storage.

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean ?

Comment: I get this error message: 
Build failed: *** Error compiling './main.py'... Sorry: IndentationError: unexpected indent (main.py, line 29); Error ID: 49c34848
The function failst o run

Comment: Please include the error description in your question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In Python indentation is very important.

In your function `upload_bloburl`, I think you messed it up. You should try:

```
def upload_bloburl(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):   
    storage_client = storage.Client() 
    
    file = urllib.request.urlopen(source_file_name)

    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_string(ET.tostring(files, encoding='UTF-8',xml_declaration=True, method='xml').decode('UTF-8'),content_type='application/xml')
    
    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name))

    return f'Success!'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your code is exactly the same as mine?! I commented out the last line of my code "upload_bloburl..." but this also doens't help

Comment: It is not the same @ChristopherSindt. The line that starts with `blob.upload_from_string` has 4 space indent